# Why L.polygon works in a way but not in another

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geojson, leaflet.draw

Good day,
I am sorry if my question could be basic but I think I do have a problem to convert a string to an array.

I am trying to add a polygon to a map (or to a layer). I extracted some polygon coordinates from a MYSQL database to show it into a map.

First here is my code:

```
function getGeofences(devise_id){


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "maps/sql/getGeofences.php",
    data: {devise_id:devise_id},
    success: result,
    error: error,
    dataType: "json"
  });

  function error(data)
  {
    console.log("Error getGeofences");
    console.log(data);
  }

  function result(data){
    console.log("Geofences from DB");

    for (var i = data.features.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      console.log(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates);

     //var polygon = L.polygon(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates, {color: 'red'});
    var polygon = L.polygon([[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625],[51.169011079452,-1.494140625],[51.158676864424,-0.8624267578125],[51.505323411493,-0.889892578125],[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625]] , {color: 'red'});
      polygon.addTo(map);
    }

  }
}
```

This:

```
console.log(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates);
```

shows/prints that:

> "[[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625],[51.169011079452,-1.494140625],[51.158676864424,-0.8624267578125],[51.505323411493,-0.889892578125],[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625]]"

I do not understand why this

```
var polygon = L.polygon([[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625],[51.169011079452,-1.494140625],[51.158676864424,-0.8624267578125],[51.505323411493,-0.889892578125],[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625]] , {color: 'red'});
```

works!

But this:

```
var polygon = L.polygon(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates, {color: 'red'});
```

does not work!

Keeping in mind, this:

```
data.features[i].geometry.coordinates
```

print that:

> [[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625],[51.169011079452,-1.494140625],[51.158676864424,-0.8624267578125],[51.505323411493,-0.889892578125],[51.436888577205,-1.373291015625]]

I think, it is because the content of

```
data.features[i].geometry.coordinates
```

is, in fact, a string with several '[[]]'

Now, I do not know how to convert the above string to an rwally array. So, I do not know what is exactly true in my written, but I need to "parse" the content of

```
data.features[i].geometry.coordinates
```

and I do not know how!

Would you suggest me a solution?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(data.features[i].geometry.coordinates)`

Comment: For me, it was because the lat/lng pairing that is returned in data.features[i].geometry.coordinates is actually an array of [lon, lat]. You need to switch the places back to [lat, lon] in the data object.